# Rhymes for purple, orange, and silver

Tags: pronunciation, poetry, rhymes

Are there any rhymes for the words *purple*, *orange* and *silver*? One of the apps on my phone says that nothing in the English dictionary rhymes with these words, and I'd like to know if this is really true.

Answer (score 3):

You could check for the rhymes in many sources, for example, http://www.rhymezone.com.

> **silver** - *Wilver* (a nickname), *chilver* (a ewe lamb), *pilver* (urban: "The feeling one has after staying awake far too late doing nothing productive and knowing all the while that one is doing nothing productive")
>
> **orange** -  *sporange*, *Blorenge* (a mountain in Wales) 
>   (source: http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/t22.html)
>
> **purple** - *turtle*, *hurtle* (to move or fall with great speed and force), *burble* (continuous murmuring noise) etc. "Purple"has many words for its rhyme.

Comment: The asker is expected do that homework, though. :)